# Export service from another module in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a reusable service within a separate module, much like [Angular 2's styleguide](https://angular.io/styleguide). However I get an error when I trying to use that service within another service:

`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AttendanceSummaryService:`

Here is my core module:

```
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { throwIfAlreadyLoaded } from './module-import-guard';
import { HttpClientService } from './httpClient.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
     exports: [],
     declarations: [],
     providers: [HttpClientService]
})
export class CoreModule {
    constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
        throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
    }
}
```

My `HttpClientService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '');
    }

    get(url) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
        return this.http.get(url, {
            headers: headers
        });
    }

    post(url, data) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
        return this.http.post(url, data, {
            headers: headers
        });
    }
}
```

And my app.module which imports the core module:

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AttendanceSummaryService } from './home/attendance-summary.service';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { HttpClientService } from './core/httpClient.service';

import {FormControl, FormGroup,  ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AttendanceSummaryComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClientService,
    AttendanceSummaryService    

  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) { }
}
```

And the service which consumes the `HttpClientService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AttendanceSummary } from './attendance-summary.model';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientService } from '../core/httpClient.service';


Injectable()
export class AttendanceSummaryService {

    private apiBaseUrl = '/api/v1/agency/attendances/';
    constructor(private http: HttpClientService) { }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are getting error because you forgot `@` before `Injectable` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AttendanceSummary } from './attendance-summary.model';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientService } from '../core/httpClient.service';

@Injectable()
export class AttendanceSummaryService {

    private apiBaseUrl = '/api/v1/agency/attendances/';
    constructor(private http: HttpClientService) { }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

For others finding this question. In your module, you may have your service listed in **exports**. It should be in your **providers**; not in imports, declarations, or exports.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
     exports: [],
     declarations: [],
     providers: [export-service-here]
})
```

Comment: Do you have an example? how do you export something in a provider?